# Date difference in months

Tags: ruby

I need to calculate the date difference in months for each consecutive pair of dates in an array in order to classify it by the frequency of the dates, e.g., monthly, quarterly, yearly.

This involves parsing the array of strings into an array of dates

```
array_of_dates = Array.new
array_of_strings.each do |str|
  array_of_dates << Date.strpdate str, "%Y%m%d"
end
```

And calculating date difference for each consecutive pair of dates

```
diffs = Array.new  
array.of.dates.each_cons(2) do |a,b|
  diffs << b - a
end
```

This return an array of ratios, e.g.:

```
=> [(31/1), (29/1), (31/1), (30/1), (31/1)]
```

However months haven't got the same length. Is there any way to return this difference in months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the number of months between two dates is to do this:

```
   months_between = finish.month - start.month + 12 * (finish.year - start.year)
```

Also, creating arrays with `Array.new` and filling them in with loops is not very idiomatic Ruby.  Usually you would just create the target array directly from the source array using `map`:

```
array_of_dates = array_of_strings.map { |s| Date.strptime s, "%Y%m%d" }

diffs = array_of_dates.each_cons(2).map { 
  |a, b| b.month - a.month + 12 * (b.year - a.year) 
}
```

You could even do it all in one step, if you don't need the array of dates for something else:

```
diffs = array_of_strings.map {|s| Date.strptime s, "%Y%m%d" }.each_cons(2).map {
  |a, b|
  b.month - a.month + 12 * (b.year - a.year)
}
```